# Android Studio Doesn't Update Automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, auto-update

When I go to `Help -> Check for Update` in android studio. It show me this window:

[image]

So I click on Download button, for starting downloading.

**But It sends me to [the Canary channel to download the latest Beta version.](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/)**

What should I do? Am I supposed to reinstall it? Or is there some way for it to automatically update?

---

Note: my update settings:

[image]

Comment: Android studio 2.1 cannot be a delta update from 1.* I guess. You may have to download the full set up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I ran in to this as well when I updated to 2.0.

Perhaps because it's a significant major release and update, it can't be installed as a patch to the current version you have (or because your current version is too old), though I'm not sure why it's redirecting you to the Canary channel.

Do a fresh install of [Android Studio 2.0](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/builds/2-0), import your settings from your already installed version, and delete the old version.

Answer (score -1):

you have to check updates for beta to download AS 2.0

Comment: I'm going to install stable version NOT beta version.

Comment: ok then, try pressing ignore this update and check again for updates, maybe 2.0 stable will show this time